# How to add Click Event on FlatList Item in React Native?

Tags: list, react-native, click

I am working in demo Application for learning `React native` And I need to render clickable `FlatList` item.

Here is `Render` and `itemClick` function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <FlatListData list={this.state.itemList} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

itemClick(item){
  console.log('click on item', item);
}
```

I have already declare `FlatListData` functional component for that :

```
const FlatListData = ({list}) => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={list}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={itemList}
      />
    );
};
```

In `FlatList` component, `RenderItem` attribute have again custom component for single item i.e :

```
const itemList = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.itemClick(item)} style={styles.catalogContainer}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: item.img}}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

But this code is not working. It will give me error like : `Undefined is not an object (eveluting _this.itemClick)`

**Here in which way and where Should I write click function for item ?**

**Any one have a answer that can solve my problem ?**

**NOTE :**

1. All code is written in one `js file`. My `Render`  function is inside my class component. and other two `declarative` component are out of that class component.
2. I need that item inside that click function. But I don't know how to pass parameter inside function.

Comment: Where is the `itemClick` function?

Comment: `ItemClick` function is inside my class Component.

Comment: I think We should pass this function into custom component via props and then again  pass into `RenderItem` custom component via props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to fix your problem.

1. You need to move your `itemClick` function inside `itemList` as an arrow function.

```
const itemList = ({ item, index }) => {
  itemClick = item => {
    console.log("click on item", item);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      // onPress={this.itemClick(item)}
      onPress={() => this.itemClick(item)}
      style={styles.catalogContainer}
    >
      <Image source={{ uri: item.img }} style={styles.imageStyle} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

2. Pass your `itemClick` function as props to child component

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatListData list={this.state.itemList} onItemClick={this.itemClick} />
        </View>
    );
}

itemClick = (item) => {
    console.log('click on item', item);
}
```

Now you can call `onItemClick` prop inside `itemList`

```
const FlatListData = ({ list, onItemClick }) => {
  itemList = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onItemClick(item)}
      style={styles.catalogContainer}
    >
      <Image source={{ uri: item.img }} style={styles.imageStyle} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={list}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={this.itemList}
    />
  );
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya If you want to handle it through ```props``` checked modified answer.